# Can sympy integrate an expression with Heaviside in the denominator?

Tags: sympy, symbolic-integration

I'd like to do something like:

```
integrate(1/(1 + Heaviside(x)),x)
```

It just returns `Integral(1/(Heaviside(x) + 1), x)` unevaluated.

The problem is that `Heaviside(0)`, is not defined. In Mathematica, for example, there is the `UnitStep` function, which is like the `Heaviside`, except that `UnitStep(0)` is equal to 1. Can I mimic this in sympy?

I've tried Heaviside(x,1) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is `Heaviside(0)`. It's just that sympy doesn't have the code to handle this particular case in the integration routines. You can help it along by rewriting the Heaviside as a Piecewise:

```
In [36]: Integral(1/(Heaviside(x) + 1), x).rewrite(Piecewise).doit()
Out[36]: 
⎧x  for x < 0
⎪            
⎨x           
⎪─  otherwise
⎩2
```